Как сконвертировать модель .pt (PyTorch) в torchscript.pt для работы в DJL?
Я пытаюсь воспользоваться моделью YOLOv5l.pt для распознавания объектов на экране компьютера. DJL не принимает: ai.djl.engine.EngineException: PytorchStreamReader failed locating file constants.pkl: file not found. Прочитал, что надо сконвертировать модель в формат .torchscript.pt. Попытался:
import torch
import sys

sys.path.append("C:/Users/user/Downloads/Yolo/yolov5")

from models.common import DetectMultiBackend

model = DetectMultiBackend("...")

example_input = torch.rand(1, 3, 640, 640)
traced_model = torch.jit.trace(model, example_input)

traced_model.save("...")

Не получилось:
RuntimeError: Tracer cannot infer type of [tensor([[[6.63067e+00, 4.48799e+00, 1.29999e+01,  ..., 1.77943e-03, 8.68350e-04, 2.78321e-03], # Прочие веса

Попытался воспользоваться файлом export.py:
python export.py --weights C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/AZComplex/Clicker/plugins/Smart Searcher/resources/yolov5l.pt --include torchscript

Тоже ошибка:
Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\mpmath\\__init__.py'

Как избежать ошибок и использовать DJL для работы с YOLO?

Здесь что-то такое обсуждают, но я так и не понял итог https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/9341

@CrazyElf, я тоже не понял :(
